# IntelliJ Scala configuration issue

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea

So, I downloaded Scala and configured paths, I can run Scala console from terminal, Scala plugin is installed and **"hello world" is running**...

The problem is that, when I write a "hello world" program:

```
object First {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println(12)
   }
}
```

it says: `Cannot resolve symbol println`

As I said, I can run this program and it prints out 12... Also, if I create a List or an array it "cannot resolve symbol" but everything runs with no problem at all...

In most cases I've found, there was problem with Java set up, but that's not the case here...

Comment: Could it be that intellij cannot find the JDK/Scala library maybe? Check "module settings" to se that you have a selecteded JDK!

Comment: i solved a problem just by reinstalling scala (delete old dirs, copy new ones)...all settings in intellij remained the same so I have not idea why it was not working in the first place

and it is an ultimate edition...

Answer (score 51):

Within <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Project Structure</kbd>, make sure that there is a scala library in <kbd>Project Settings</kbd>\<kbd>Libraries</kbd>
Or, make sure that you have added scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar to your project.

If it is still acting strange, try <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Invalidate Cache/Restart</kbd>

I had a similar issue with IntelliJ for an SBT project I started, with a correctly installed Scala 2.11 library, etc.  Invalidate Cache fixed it so that IntelliJ could find the symbols.

Comment: I was really furious to waste time on this kind of error. Invalidate Cache/Restart worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Proceed with caution here – IntelliJ couldn't find my project once I did this. I had to re-init. the project. The host of bugs with this IDE is crazy.

Comment: During intellij startup Ctrl + N works and it locates scala source file. However, once the ide is up , it does find the scala file with Crtl + N. I'm using intellij 2018.2.2 ultimate and have installed scala plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure, that you have scala-library.jar and scala-compiler in your project libraries.

Then try invalidating cache (File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart).

If it's still not working, try reloading all your maven projects. You can either reimport them manually or go to Maven Projects->Reimport All Maven Projects (blue arrows).

I had similar issue and the last thing worked for me.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue when I use the idea 15, and fixed it in these 2 steps:

1. File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> Scala SDK -> your version -> OK
2. Maven Projects -> choose your scala project -> Lifecycle -> clean -> compile

Done

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but it worked with my environment. Navigate to:

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Modules</kbd>

Then, when I tried to apply a minor change, I got a message about how the Content Roots was being shared between two different Modules (a conflict). After removing the conflicting Content Root(s) from one of the Modules, IntelliJ started resolving symbols correctly.

You will see Content Roots on the right-hand side of the dialog box under module "Sources" tab.

I have no idea if the conflict in "Content Root" was what kept IntelliJ from resolving symbols, but fixing this error cleared everything up without having to change anything else.

Comment: These are no longer my words. If you have this much time on your hands then you should provide your own response.

Comment: @stites' edits are perfectly consistent with https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing and improve the quality of the answer.  Even far more substantive edits than this are encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

if your version IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4

Worksheet configuration error:: Can't find Scala module to run

project structure > Modules > + > new modules > scala > scala

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - it turned out to be caused by me upgrading Java on my Mac, so that my JDK's path (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home`) was no longer valid.  I went into my Project Structure settings and updated the path to `/Library/Java/Home`, then the project could see the proper Java libraries.

[image]