# Evaluating expressions in Scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Just downloaded Scala to learn it a few minutes ago.
So following their help file in creating a worksheet listed here:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html

I did the same thing.
But I don't see anything in the right pane.
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to push on green button?

Comment: @DmytroMitin  the Play Button above it ? Yes I did. . Their other example that was HelloScala with OBJECT , that one worked.

Comment: Every time you push this button it shows that it compiles it. Maybe it needs a sec to detect changes or just push the button again. They have a few settings like running it as REPL or plain, etc. Try to play with those. I personally find that regular scala REPL is much more robust, or just make a normal SBT project and run your code non-interactively.

Comment: Recommend checking the event log for any errors such as **Worksheet configuration error:: Can't find Scala module to run** which might point to the root cause such as [scala library configuratuon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27263394/8379597)